# I don't know what's wrong

Tags: java, if-statement, linked-list

```
if(handler.obj.isEmpty())
    handler.addObject(new Box(x, y, ID.Box));
else{
    for(int i = 0; i < handler.obj.size(); i++){
        Object tempObj = handler.obj.get(i);
        if (tempObj.getX() == x && tempObj.getY() == y && tempObj.getId() == ID.Box)
            handler.removeObect(tempObj);
        else
            handler.addObject(new Box(x, y, ID.Box));
    }
}
```

the `handler.addObject()` in the `else` statement seems unreachable or doesn't work

**From comment:**

```
public class Handler {
    LinkedList<Object> obj = new LinkedList<Object>();
    public void tick(){
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.size();i++){
            Object tempObj = obj.get(i);
            tempObj.tick();
        }
    }
    public void render(Graphics g){
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.size(); i++){
            Object tempObj = obj.get(i);
            tempObj.render(g);
        }
    }
    public void addObject(Object obj){
        this.obj.add(obj);
    }
    public void removeObect(Object obj){
        this.obj.remove(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You have a missing `}`. Learn how to debug your code. Add `System.out.println(...)` statements to print out the values of variables so that you can see what's happening.

Comment: @Jesper: I don't think they're missing a `}` (well, okay, in **my** view they're missing several pairs of `{` and `}`, but the code above has what few blocks it uses correctly paired up).

Comment: we don't know what's in handler.  Print it out.

Comment: sorry, I actually noticed that its missing a } but I have no idea how to edit it so yeah..

Comment: You can ignore for us by deleting it

Comment: @klooj always put {} brackets even you have single statement .it make your code more readable

Comment: @FastSnail I would argue that indentation does more for *readability* than brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see. Assume first time it runs, `x,y` is `1,1`. So you add `Box(1,1)`.

Next time is run, let's assume `x,y` is `2,3`. So, enter `for` loop:

- `i = 0`: Not same `x,y`, so enter `else`, and add `Box(2,3)`.
- `i = 1`: Same as `x,y` (yeah, we just added it), so enter `if` and remove `Box(2,3)`.

Result: Box added and removed again.

Oh yeah, a debugger would have told you the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `for` loop ends in the wrong place.  This causes two undesirable symptoms.

- Firstly, you're adding your new `Box` once for every element in your list that *doesn't* match the box, instead of adding it just once.
- Secondly, you're removing some of those new `Box` objects that you just added, once you get to the end of the loop.

I would recommend rewriting the method like this.  Notice how the `for` loop ends before the new object is added - this makes sure that the object is added at most once.  Also notice the `return` statement after an object is removed - this can be done because once the object is removed, the method has no more work to do.

```
public void addOrRemoveBox(int x, int y) {
    for(int i = 0; i < handler.obj.size(); i++){
        Object tempObj = handler.obj.get(i);
        if (tempObj.getX() == x && tempObj.getY() == y && tempObj.getId() == ID.Box) {
            handler.removeObect(tempObj);
            return;
         }
    }
    handler.addObject(new Box(x, y, ID.Box));
}
```

Lastly, you appear to have written your own class called `Object` (otherwise this code wouldn't compile).  This is probably a bad idea, because it will cause you to get confused between *your* `Object` class, and the `Object` class that's built into Java.  I suggest you rename that class.